# Enjoying something more because I know it will end

Tags: single-word-requests

Suddenly enjoying something more because I know it's about to end/be taken away. Is there a word for this feeling?

Scenario: Getting to the bottom of a bag of M&Ms, and realizing a sudden greater joy of the last 2-3 candies- knowing they'll be entire gone soon.

Comment: This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to *enjoy* something more just because it's about to end. If anything, there could be a tinge of sorrow to your enjoyment (if not outright sorrow) because you know it won't last.

People who enjoy something but know it won't last might actually call their feeling [*bittersweet*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet).

On the other hand, you could be said to have a greater [**appreciation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appreciation) for something when you know it's about to end.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** : a feeling or expression of admiration, approval, or gratitude
> // I want to express my *appreciation* for all you've done.
> // a small token of our *appreciation*
> **b** : JUDGMENT, EVALUATION
> *especially* : a favorable critical estimate
> **c** : sensitive awareness
> *especially* : recognition of aesthetic values
> // a class in music *appreciation*

---

People who know that something is about to end don't enjoy it more *because* of that fact. Instead, increased enjoyment generally happens because they've deliberately chosen to pay more attention to it, forgetting about other things that would normally distract them.

In terms of enjoyment, it's a two-stage step of causation. The fact of something about to end causes you to concentrate on it more, and it's this increased concentration on it that can lead to increased enjoyment.

Meanwhile knowing that something is about to end *can* directly cause a greater appreciation of it.

Comment: Whoa, I think you just hit the nail on the head. Thanks for the insightful response. The more I think about it. Appreciation is the word, and it gets increased with newfound concentration. Thank you!